# How to keep SVG separate from HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to have a clean and simple HTML page that includes SVGs. I could drop the SVG into the HTML but that would make the file huge and ugly. I'd rather just keep the SVGs in separate files and link them into the page somehow.

I found out you could use an  tag like so:

```
<object data="vector.svg"></object>
```

But this doesn't allow me to style the svg externally. I'd have to embed all the styling in the SVG itself, which I don't want to do.

Is there a way to have the SVG loaded externally, but still styled in an external CSS file?

Comment: you're looking for trouble, externally loaded SVG causes a lot of issues. Just use any HTML "prettify" tool if that is really an issue for you and avoid more serious concerns

Answer (score 3):

You can have an external CSS file, you just need to include it from the SVG file. Stick an [xml-stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/1999/06/REC-xml-stylesheet-19990629/) before the root `<svg>` element e.g.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg-stylesheet.css" ?>   
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
</svg>
```

In UAs that support html you can also use an html [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-link-element.html) element to include external CSS files. You don't even need to wrap it in a `foreignObject` element as it isn't rendered.